# How to escape imported partial in Nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks

I would like to escape the HTML code from an imported file in Nunjucks.

```
{% include "item.html" %}
```

The file "item.html" contains following code:

```
<strong>bold text</strong>
```

I would like the parent file (which includes item.html) to have the following output:

```
&lt;strong&gt;bold text&lt;/strong&gt;
```

I tried surrounding the include with an escape filter:

```
{% filter escape %}
  {% include "item.html" %}
{% endfilter %}
```

However in that case the file doesn't get included correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify "correctly"? Does an error get thrown, or does the text not get escaped?

Comment: No error gets thrown, there's just no output when surrounding the include with the escape filter.

Comment: @AdriaanMeuris did you find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't, but managed to get it working using Handlebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your snippet on Gulp + `gulp-nunjucks-render@2.0.0`, it *does* produce the desired effect:

```
{% filter escape %}
{% include "partials/test.html"  %}
{% endfilter %}
```

Output:
[image: filter escape works]